# Karate framework - How to check conditional OR for two string for a attribute

Tags: cucumber, karate

I want to compare two string and need to check for any of the string value for an attribute as below : "firstName": "#? _ == '#string1' || _ == '#string2'".

this I provided in JSON as below

```
{
  "id":"#number",
  "firstName":"#string",
  "lastName":"#string",
  "city":  "#? _ == '#Boston' || _ == '#Bijing'"
}
```

but it is not comparing string ? please help. AM I correct here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need for using `#` before the string if it is not a variable reference

```
{
  "id":"#number",
  "firstName":"#string",
  "lastName":"#string",
  "city":  "#string? _ == 'Boston' || _ == 'Bijing'"
}
```